# NativeScript for Windows error: Android SDK Build-tools v29 You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

When trying to follow the NativeScript for Vue Quick Start here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/
 in June 2019, the Android SDK is version 29.

At the command `$ tns run android --bundle` or when running `tns doctor` I get the following error: `You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'` and yes, I also get the message `Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.` BUT of course it is version 29, not `'>=23 <=28'`

Other SO responses do not seem to address this problem.

How to install an older version in this case?

Comment: Ok, adding my own answer so others do not waste time trying to resolve this.

Comment: Ok, adding my own answer so others do not waste time trying to resolve this.

1. Old versions of the Build Tools are here: https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools
Download v28.0.3 and unzip it.

2. Go to your existing build tools location. eg %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools
You will see the current install folder eg 29.0.0. Add a parallel folder matching the one you just downloaded eg 28.0.3 and copy the unzipped files into it.

3. `tns doctor` should now be happy.

Comment: You can use Android Studio, it provides GUI interface to manage your SDK and Tools. Go to Tools -> SDK Manager, that will give you list of available SDKs. Simply check api level 28 and hit OK should install it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Except there didn't seem to be a way to get older versions. The only build tool version listed was 29. Maybe I missed the bleeding obvious?

Comment: OK. My Bad! I missed the comment and the check box for `Show package details`!!! Doh! Thanks @manoj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Android SDK manager, go to the SDK Tools tab and then select the Show Package Details checkbox.  Older versions will then be displayed.

[image: Where to click]